# Launch a bash script when enterring password to log in?

Tags: bash, login, scripts

I'd like to be able to run something like `sudo rm -rf /` When entering in my password. Just in case I ever need to wipe everything at once before I even login.

I know there are security concerns, so in a perfect world, I'd like to be able to set it up in .bashrc so I would type in something less obvious.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: how would you log-in if you wipe everything?

Comment: What? Running `sudo rm -rf /` would clear your installation (and all files on any mounted device). Luckily they prevented it to be run.

Comment: Something less obvious ? Alias this command like `alias notwhatyouthink='sudo rm -rf /'` in .bashrc and if you ever need it , run `notwhatyouthink` command

Comment: You do realize that rm -rf / destroys the whole system , right ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Maybe @terdon wants to answer this one :)

Comment: @Serg actually, `rm -rf /` does nothing but print an error message. This is defined by the current [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html).

Comment: As it looks like you're concerned about security, you should notice, that simply deleting everything doesn't help much (deleted files can be recovered). You should rather wipe/shred that data with e.g. `sudo shred -n1 /dev/sda`. Or encrypt the whole system.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest a slightly different approach. Create a new user, let's call him "harakiri" and set it up so that when you log in as `harakiri`, a command is executed that deletes everything on your hard drive.

1. Create the new user

   ```
   sudo adduser harakiri
   ```
2. Create a `harakiri` script that deletes everything on your drive:

   ```
   echo "rm -rf --no-preserve-root /" | sudo tee /usr/bin/harakiri
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/harakiri
   ```

   We now have the `harakiri` command which, when run as root, will delete everything on your `/`.
3. Add a line to their `.profile` that will make them run the `harakiri` script.

   ```
   echo "sudo harakiri" | sudo tee ~harakiri/.profile
   ```
4. Add them to the `sudoers` group

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG sudo harakiri
   ```
5. Allow user `harakiri` to run `sudo harakiri` with no password. Run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

   ```
   harakiri  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/harakiri
   ```

Exit and save the file and that's it. Now, you can just log in as `harakiri` instead of your normal user and that will delete everything on your drive.

---

#### CAVEATS

1. This is extremely dangerous and can delete everything on your hard drive. Try with a less destructive command first to make sure everything is working as expected.
2. Even if you delete everything, it is relatively easy for an expert to retrieve your files. You might want to look into utilities like [shred](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/shred.1.html).

Comment: I like this answer more than the other =) You have my +1 for this funny thing… :)

Comment: @A.B.: I like both!

Answer (score 6):

If you really *need* to have this happen when you log in as your regular user, you could also create a bogus X session that runs the `rm` command.

1. Create the `.desktop` file. Run `sudo nano /usr/share/xsessions/harakiri.desktop` and add these lines:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Harakiri
   Comment=This session will destroy everything
   Exec=harakiri
   Icon=
   Type=Application
   ```
2. The `rm` command needs to be launched as root in order to delete files on `/` but the sessions are launched as your user. We therefore need an extra script. The first is the session script which in turn will call the one that launched the `rm` command:

   ```
   echo "sudo /usr/bin/harakiri.sh" | sudo tee /usr/bin/harakiri
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/harakiri
   ```
3. Create the script that will launch the `rm` command:

   ```
   echo "rm -rf --no-preserve-root /" | sudo tee /usr/bin/harakiri.sh
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/harakiri.sh
   ```
4. Give your user the right to run it with no password. Run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

   ```
   youruser  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/harakiri.sh
   ```

Now you will be able to choose the `harakiri` session from the login screen and that will delete everything on your drive.

---

#### CAVEATS

1. This is extremely dangerous and can delete everything on your hard drive. Try with a less destructive command first to make sure everything is working as expected.
2. Even if you delete everything, it is relatively easy for an expert to retrieve your files. You might want to look into utilities like [shred](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/shred.1.html).

Comment: `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` will not clear your system. It will delete files until `/bin/rm` stops working. `ldd /bin/rm` shows some of these files. System suicide is hard! (Boot from elsewhere and murder is easier, but not the answer). Why not use an encrypted directory?

Comment: @waltinator Binaries and dynamic libraries are loaded in memory at load time, so the `rm` process you started can (and will) run pretty much to completion. You won't be able to start another one when the first one deletes its own binary, but the first one will certainly keep running unimpeded and clear out most of your filesystem. In any case, needless to say you will not be rebooting successfully after `rm` is finished with your filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: what you want to do is not impossible, but more difficult then you think, as you need to:

1. [Boot into a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)
2. Execute a delete command (and `rm --recursive --force /` will not work)

   If you try it out, you'll just get:

   ```
   rm --recursive --force /
   rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’
   ```

So the better option would be to:

1. [How can I securely erase a hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive)

Or even better:

2. [Enable disk encryption after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation) so that no one has access in the first place.

Another piece of free advice: [start making back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before you even try any of the above.

Comment: I don't know what the user is really trying to do, but the latest versions of GNU `rm` have the `--no-preserve-root` which should allow you to operate (even using `--recursive` on `/`)

Comment: @kos: Yes, I know....  Try it out and you'll understand!