# Ubuntu 16.04 full disk encryption after installation

Tags: encryption

**I know this was asked for previous releases. Has anything changed for 16.04?** The official documentation hasn't been updated for a while.

If FDE after installation is not possible, what about encrypt /home (for all users, not just one). Any outstanding bug preventing it from working properly? I have hit so many bugs in 16.04.

Comment: Did it with 16.04 - https://askubuntu.com/a/1107295/723997