# LVM Encryption on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, encryption, ssd, lvm

I have set up a small home server a few days ago and already configured some things. Unfortunately I have not selected the option Excryption of the LVM during the installation. Now I am looking for a way to encrypt my LVM without reinstalling it. My LVM consists of two disks. I want to encrypt them using YubiKey.

Is there a procedure? My ideas on this would be:

- Create a new VG next to the existing one. This will be encrypted. A snapshot of the old VG is created. Data from snapshot is transferred to the new encrypted VG. Can I create more than one VolumeGroup on two SSDs?
- Other idea: create snapshot of LVM on external media. Reinstall server (LVM with encryption) Restore snapshot from external media.

In general it is important to me that my data and especially the previous configuration inbs. docker itself, portainer, unifi controller can all be used further.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable disk encryption after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation)

Comment: ok, so i understand that i need to reinstall the server, good. but what about the idea of Yubikey and a data restore?