# How to encrypt Linux data on a drive with Windows partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, encryption

I just got a new LG Gram 17" laptop and have shrunk the Windows partition to 50 GB. (To my surprise, the system already uses 45 GB of it!) Anyway, I would love to keep the ability to boot into native Windows. I have successfully installed Ubuntu Mate on another partition and dual boot works. However, I want my data on the Linux partition to be encrypted, and it seems that now the preferred method for Linux is encrypting the entire drive. Is there a not-too-complex way to encrypt my data that will leave the Windows partitions (not only the "C" drive but the other little partitions it uses) untouched?

Comment: Hello, if you want to encrypt a partition, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation)'s already an answer. The encryption for individual files are much simple and fail-safe method. For example, in the case, you want to rescue the OS and don't want to read your document to other people. GNU Privacy Guard GNUPG aka `gpg` is traditional and trustworthy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Thank you. I was aware that encryption of the home folder was possible, but read that this is no longer the preferred method of ensuring privacy. So I was looking for a way to encrypt the entire partition. Encrypting only the home directory leaves the rest of the system (especially /tmp) unencrypted. There may be other reasons as well, I don't know.

Comment: @KeithBennett, sounds professional. I am happy that you found the way. `cryptsetup <option> <device name>` would create a new encrypted partition. You can install a new Ubuntu or clone your MATE system onto it. Simplest way: Abandon Ubuntu installation and overwrite a new Ubuntu, installer can make an encrypted partition. Choose "something else" when it asks where to install. NOTE: only a few people on earth can open encrypted files/drives. No one can repair your OS or salvage data.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Thanks. Does this mean I could boot from a live Linux DVD, create the partition, run cryptsetup on it, and then run the Ubuntu installation on that partition?

Comment: @KeithBennett, Yes sir. It is the simplest and easiest way, I believe. Details: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/encrypt-system-disk-installing-ubuntu/