# Is there a way to enable or configure Full Disk Encryption (LUKS) after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

Is there a way to enable or configure Full Disk Encryption (LUKS) after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable disk encryption after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Yes. This is a similar already answered question that says how you can do it ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444931/is-there-a-way-to-encrypt-disk-without-formatting-it?newreg=e2771db0343d44009d95ac188a722cf6)).
**But you shouldn't**; since there is a big chance of data loss. The better way is to backup your data, format the partition LUKS enabled and reinstall the OS.
[Cryptsetup's FAQs](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup) also mentions:

> 2.5 Can I encrypt an existing, non-empty partition to use LUKS?
>
> There is no converter, and it is not really needed.  The way to do
> this is to make a backup of the device in question, securely wipe the
> device (as LUKS device initialization does not clear away old data),
> do a luksFormat, optionally overwrite the encrypted device, create a
> new filesystem and restore your backup on the now encrypted device.
> Also refer to sections "Security Aspects" and "Backup and Data
> Recovery". For backup, plain GNU tar works well and backs up anything
> likely to be in a filesystem.

If you really want to do this, of course **BACKUP ALL YOUR DATA**.